# API Equivalent of running SomeActiveX.Exe /regserver

Tags: vb6, activex-exe

I need to register an ActiveX exe programmatically and Shell(SomeActiveX.Exe /regserver) is not sufficient. Is anyone aware of an API equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DllRegisterServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682162%28VS.85%29.aspx) to register a COM component programatically, if it's an in-process com object.  Here is a [VB6 example on MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173091).

To register an out of process COM object, things get tricky.  See [Exposing ActiveX Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221669.aspx). The Hello Sample shows some of the options.  [Larry Osterman blogged about this](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2006/01/11/511647.aspx) for background info.

In general, if you need to do this to an EXE, shelling out to *.EXE /regserver will be much easier.

Comment: I may be handling something incorrectly, but I thought DLLRegisterServer could only be used for DLL and OCX?

Comment: Wow, if that's as good as it gets, I better get my refactor hat out. Thanks for the resources.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using regsvr32 also. This should be sufficient:

```
Shell(SomeActiveX.Exe /regserver)
Shell(regsvr32 SomeActiveX.Exe)
```

Comment: Regsvr32 doesn't work with ActiveX Exe's. In this particular case I can't use Shell.